# How to make pandas.DataFrame.rank go from 0 to 1?

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I currently have:

```
df.groupby('Team')['Score'].rank(pct=True)
```

I want **0 to represent the individual with the lowest score** on each team. I have many teams in which there should be a seperate percentile calculation.

How can I define the range calculation for each team's percentile calculation?

Comment: Just do a `1-x` to flip 1->0 to be 0->1?

Comment: @noah I don'tunderstand. Are you able to show an example?

Comment: `rank(pct=True)` will give you values from 0 to 1 where 1 is the highest. Are you just trying to make it so 0 is highest instead? Basically reverse the order? If so then whatever value x you have you then just want 1-x. So `1-df.groupby('Team')['Score'].rank(pct=True)`

Comment: Or just `ascending=False` instead of the default `ascending=True`

Comment: @noah I am trying to make it to 0 is the lowest. The default rank function does not do this.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want compared to what rank is giving you. Consider adding some sample data/results to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Google led me here. I am adding the python code (& R equivalent) for future reference.

```py
import pandas as pd
pp = pd.Series([12, 15, 11, 13, None, 12])
qq = (pp.rank(method = 'min') - 1) / (pp.count() - 1)      #Percent Rank
print(*qq)
## 0.25 1.0 0.0 0.75 nan 0.25

print(*pp.rank(method = 'max', pct = True))                #Cumulative Distance
## 0.6 1.0 0.2 0.8 nan 0.6
```

```r
library(dplyr)
aa <- c(12, 15, 11, 13, NA, 12)
percent_rank(aa)                                          #Percent Rank
## [1] 0.25 1.00 0.00 0.75   NA 0.25

cume_dist(aa)                                             #Cumulative Distance
## [1] 0.6 1.0 0.2 0.8  NA 0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['percentile'] = pd.qcut(df['Score'], 1, labels=False)
```

This will add a new column to the frame and calculate the percentile for each row based on the Score value, ranging from 0 to 1.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work correctly as I have different subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `df.groupby('Team')['Score'].rank(pct=True, ascending=True, method='average')`